# MySQL event scheduler refresh error PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code in my php, but everytime I refresh the page it says Event 'expired' already exist. any way that it would not pop up anymore?

```
$auto = mysql_query("CREATE EVENT expired ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE DO UPDATE stocks SET status='expired' WHERE expdate < NOW() ") or die (mysql_error());
```

Thanks

Comment: Why bother setting `status='expired'` at all?  Can't that simply be detected by querying `WHERE expdate < NOW()` when required?

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, every time you refresh the page it will attempt to create a new event with the name `expired`.

If you only want to create one event and never worry about it again (and based on that query, it looks like you do), you should just do it once in the database directly.

However, if you really want to keep it in your code, you could use `IF NOT EXISTS`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS expired ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE DO UPDATE stocks SET status='expired' WHERE expdate < NOW()
```

However, if all you want to do is determine the state of a stock at a give time, it might make more sense to use MySQL's `IF` logic to derive a status at any point (and not actually have a status field in your table): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

```
SELECT *, IF(expdate < NOW(), "expired", IF(expdate < NOW() + INTERVAL 10 DAYS), "critical", "fine")) AS status FROM stocks
```

Comment: yeah . saw it so thanks a lot man . :) just created a new php which will call for it . uhm btw . how would i update the same status to critical when the current date is 10days before the expiry date?